# YII2 got this error Access to font at - has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: yii2

i cant found the answer for my problem because i use yii2

HEADERS - General

> Request URL:
>   https://source.myweb.com/css/icons/icomoon/css/icomoon.css Request
>   Method: GET Status Code: 200  Remote Address: 104.27.189.114:443
>   Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

RESPONE HEADERS

```
cache-control: public, max-age=604800
cf-bgj: minify
cf-cache-status: HIT
cf-polished: origSize=48769
cf-ray: 4b3f84c7adf9c388-SIN
content-encoding: br
content-type: text/css
date: Thu, 07 Mar 2019 21:03:53 GMT
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
expires: Thu, 14 Mar 2019 21:03:53 GMT
last-modified: Wed, 20 Feb 2019 15:19:22 GMT
server: cloudflare
status: 200
vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
x-turbo-charged-by: LiteSpeed
```

REQUEST HHEADERS

Provisional headers are shown
Referer: https://blog.myweb.com/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Mobile Safari/537.36

i was try many answer but i cant resolved this ?

Comment: are you loading these fonts on localhost or live server?

Comment: in shared hosting, both of domain in the same host